# Determine a random View and compare it to an onClick selected one

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an application that has as his interface two rows of 3 buttons. All buttons are black, except for one which is green. The user must click on the green one, and when this happens one of the other buttons (determined randomly) turns green while the one that was pressed turns black. I'm currently stuck on the part where the app checks whether the button pressed is the green one or a wrong (=black) one. I've been trying in many different ways, all of which have gloriously failed. Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

EDIT: as requested, here's the code. It's for a slightly different interface, where a button is used to generate the random ID calling the newRandom method, while the others can only check if they're the correct one calling testRandom and if so wait for another newRandom call.

```
    public class SecondTestActivity extends Activity {


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity StaticSecondTestActivity = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);
        setupActionBar();

        // Chiude l'applicazione dopo un certo tempo
        new CountDownTimer(21000, 1000) {
             TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 textView.setText("Il Test 2 finirà in  " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 +" secondi");
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 textView.setText("Test 2 Completato!");
                 Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
                 g.setPhase(2); 
                 startMain();
                 StaticSecondTestActivity.finish();

             }
          }.start();
    }

    boolean state = false;
    int idNumber = 0;
    public void newRandom(View view) {

        int min = 1;
        int max = 6;
        Random r = new Random();
        idNumber = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        if (!state) {
            state = false;
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_button_uncorrect));
            View button1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            View button2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            View button3 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            View button4 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            View button5 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button5);
            View button6 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button6);
            View correctButton = view;
            switch (idNumber) {
            case 1:
                correctButton = button1;
                break;
            case 2:
                correctButton = button2;
                break;
            case 3:
                correctButton = button3;
                break;
            case 4:
                correctButton = button4;
                break;
            case 5:
                correctButton = button5;
                break;
            case 6:
                correctButton = button6;
                break;
            default: 
                correctButton = view;
                break;
            }
            correctButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_button_correct));
        }

    }

    public void testRandom(View view) {
        int submittedId = 0;
        View button1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        View button2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        View button3 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        View button4 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        View button5 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        View button6 = (View) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        View buttonBase = (View) findViewById(R.id.buttonBase);
        if (!view.equals(button1)) 
            submittedId = 1; 
        else if (!view.equals(button2)) 
            submittedId = 2; 
        else if (!view.equals(button3)) 
            submittedId = 3; 
        else if (!view.equals(button4)) 
            submittedId = 4; 
        else if (!view.equals(button5)) 
                submittedId = 5; 
        else if (!view.equals(button6)) 
            submittedId = 6; 
        else 
            submittedId = 0;
         if (state) {
             if (submittedId == idNumber) {
                 state = false;
                 view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_button_uncorrect));
                 buttonBase.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_button_correct));

             }
         }

    }

    protected void startMain() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}

    private void setupActionBar() {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could set tags to each of the button with there color values and use the color values when evaluating the validation mechanism.

Comment: @GauravArora The problem is I'm not just using a color, I'm using drawables...

Comment: please do post you `gloriously failed` code so that we could improve it

Comment: One thing i notices here, is that all the buttons have equal probability of getting chosen the next time. As per my understanding, you don't want the same button again to be chosen as the new 'correct button'.

Comment: @GauravArora that's something i didnt consider, but still i need to get the app to work before improving it